# Is there a way to record whatsapp calls?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, audio-recording

Do you know of a reliable (and preferably simple) method to record audio calls made using whatsapp on android phones ?

The method should record both correspondents, not just the voice of the local phone user. Permission to record the voice of the remote correspondent would be asked before recording, of course. The goal is to record an interview, where the would-be-interviewed person proposed to use whatsapp.

I've tried a few apps so far, but they seemed to record only the voice of the local phone user, or worked with normal phone calls, but not whatsapp calls. I'm not sure why.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=record+whatsapp

Answer (score 1):

The [Cube ACR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catalinagroup.callrecorder) app is able to do this.

At the top of the menu of this application, turn "Enable recording" on. Then, when calling with whatsapp, you have a button to switch recording on and off. The recordings are then available within the app in AMR format (with the free version of the application), and can be exported, for instance to your google drive.